# Is the statement *a[i]++ /= K valid?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

Array initialization Code:

```
int m = 100;
int n = 50;
int i = 0, j = 0;

float **a = (float**)malloc(m*sizeof(float*));

for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    a[i] = (float*)malloc(n*sizeof(float));
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        a[i][j] = i + j;
}
```

`a` is a 2D array and I want to traverse and update the elements of the 1D array `a[0]`

Say I want to divide all elements of a[0] by 2:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    *a[0]++ /= 2; //  instead of a[0][i] /= 2;
```

This doesn't seem to work..

Comment: Please show the actual declarations of `a`, `i`, and `K`.

Comment: Show more code, like the exact declaration of `a`.

Comment: No, `a` is *not* a 2D array, it only is an emulation of such a beast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `a` is a 2 dimensional array like `int a[10][20]`, then the given statement `a[i]++`  is "`invalid`".

The reason is that since a[i] being an array a[i] is a non-modifiable 'lvalue'.

In the above case `*a[i]` is valid but not the `a[i]++`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, although it look like a homework. If you want more interesting code, you could write this without spaces, as `*a[i]++/=K`, and finally you could attach this to the containing loop, as for example `while(p=a[i]++)*p/=K;` to make things more compressed. ;-)

Comment: And even more `int main(){int*arr[5]{0},i=0,K=1,*p;while(p=a[i]++)*p/=K;}` tooptimizedreducedfilesizeandspeed!